# codeigniter pagination total_rows dynamically

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

here is my code and my problem in comment line.

```
public function sonuc()
{
    $config['total_rows'] = 5  //i want to set here count of result instead of digit. count($data['sonuc']) does not work.. what will i do?
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $data['sonuc'] = $this->emlak_model->arama(
                        $config['per_page'], 
                        $this->uri->segment(3,0),
                        $this->input->post('semt'),
                     ); 
}
```

if i do it manually with digit, pagination will work, but i want to get total_row of query automatically, what will i do? thanks.

Comment: Can you print `$data['sonuc']` and show us the results?  Did you try to set `$config['total_rows'] = count($data['sonuc']);` after you set `$data['sonuc']`?

Comment: I helped this guy in #codeigniter irc channel, it's resolved !

Comment: @JeremieGes Can you or Yigit post the answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a fresh count of your field on each page load,you have to count all your fields with a query count:

```
$total_rows = $this->db->count_all_results('mytable');
```

check the [Codeigniter Doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

so according to your code:

```
public function sonuc()
{
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('mytable'); //put your table name here 
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $data['sonuc'] = $this->emlak_model->arama(
                        $config['per_page'], 
                        $this->uri->segment(3,0),
                        $this->input->post('semt'),
                     ); 
}
```

Comment: i solved my problem, i saw yours now. $this->db->count_all_results does not for me. because result will be changed dynamically according to user selection. :) i run the query 2 times, first i get the count of query second i process the query.